# How to cause NSString's dataUsingEncoding: method return nil?

Tags: ios, string, swift, encoding, error-handling

I have a method (initializer) I need to test:

```
public convenience init(jsonString: String, identifier: String, editable: Bool) throws {

        if let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            try self.init(jsonData: data, identifier: identifier, editable: editable)

        } else {
            throw ToggleSetJSONStringError.JSONStringEncodingError
        }
    }
```

I must write an unit test to check if it throws arbitrary  `JSONStringEncodingError` correctly. I have a difficulty coming up with a scenario when could that happen. I know `dataUsingEncoding:` will return `nil` when string is not convertible to the target encoding but I do not know how to cause that actually. I tried, f.ex.:

```
func testThatItThrowsJSONStringEncodingErrorWhenInitializedWithJSONNotConvertibleToUTF8String() {

        let jsonNonConvertibleString = ""
        do {
            let _ = try ToggleSet.init(jsonString: jsonNonConvertibleString, identifier: "not relevant here", editable: true)
            XCTFail("ToggleSetError.JSONStringError error should be thrown.")

        } catch  let e as ToggleSetJSONStringError {
            XCTAssertEqual(e, ToggleSetJSONStringError.JSONStringEncodingError)
        }
        catch {
            XCTFail("Wrong error thrown, should be: ToggleSetError.JSONStringEncodingError")
        }
    }
```

But the mentioned error is still not thrown. Any creative ideas for string which would be non-convertible to the UTF8 encoding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any `NSString` can be encoded into UTF-8 so there is no way to get `nil` with that encoding.

The only way to get `nil` from the `NSString dataUsingEncoding` method is to use an encoding that can't support the given string such as the ASCII encoding with a string containing Emoji characters.